# How can I remove the ng-repeats and ng-includes produced when compiling a templatecache

Tags: angularjs

My goal is to produce an HTML string that will be saved in a database and can be displayed in other angular apps.

I was able to get that string but any ng-repeats and ng-includes are still a part of that markup so when I try to display that HTML it essentially tries to compile it again and since there are no values within the ng-repeat or ng-bind it ends up not showing those pieces.

The markup is pretty much perfect if I can just get rid the ng-binding and ng-repeats, or possibly tell Angular to ignore the ng-repeats/ng-includes on the side I'm displaying them. Any ideas?

Comment: there isn't a native way to "compile away" the angular bindings to the **current** app;  this would break the two way binding that is the foundation of how angular works.  you can design a function to strip all the angular elements, but that requires quite a bit of knowledge of all the possible combinations of angular attributes, which isn't very efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clean it by appending the html into a temporary element. Then manipulate those elements removing classes and attributes. When done return the innerHTML

```
var $el = angular.element('<div>').append(yourHtmlString);
$el.find($el[0].querySelectorAll('[ng-repeat]').removeAttr('ng-repeat');
var result= $el.html();// raw non angular html
```

This is a bit oversimplified since you may also need to remove comments that angular uses as placeholders so is provided as concept only